# FindById is returning 2 results when only 1 is Present

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.3

I am using cakephp 2.3. The table station has a primary index on Id.

when I use the following findById function to count the number of records in the table with this id, and can see 2 results. But in the table, there is only 1 record of this id.

```
$station = $this->Station->findById($id);
$this->set('Station', $station);
```

When I run a foreach loop, the second time look begins to give Notice errors.

I am puzzled. If there is only 1 record of this id in the database, why do I get 2 as the count.

View code:

```
    $i=0; $c = count($Station); echo "Total Stations: $c"."<hr>"; 
    foreach ($Station as $station): 
       echo "Name: " . $station['Station']['name'];
    endforeach;
```

Comment: Show how you're getting the count, and how you're doing the loop. You're probably doing one of those wrong.

Comment: Have you any field line_id in Station table?

Comment: In the question, please. Code in comments has no formatting.

Comment: Your `foreach` is wrong, it should be `foreach ($station as $st)`.

Comment: `findById` doesn't return multiple rows. It returns an associative array with two elements in it, `ModelName` and `AssociatedModelName`. That's why `count()` is 2.

Comment: PHP variables are case sensitive so $station and $Station are not same make it clear

Comment: Hi Barmar. I have corrected the code as I had a set() statement in the controller. The View is also updated.

How do I get the count of the number of rows matching the id, if findById will not give the count?

Comment: Since IDs are unique, there can only be one row matching the ID.

Comment: More generally, you can use `find('count', <parameters>)` to get the count of rows matching the specified parameters.

Comment: FYI, I've never used CakePHP, I'm just reading this stuff straight out of the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for CakePHP's `find` functions can be found [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html). It says:

> findBy() functions return results like find('first')

The documentation of `find('first')` says:

> find('first', $params) will return one result. You’d use this for any case where you expect only one result.

It then shows the format of the returned result:

```
Array
(
    [ModelName] => Array
        (
            [id] => 83
            [field1] => value1
            [field2] => value2
            [field3] => value3
        )

    [AssociatedModelName] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [field1] => value1
            [field2] => value2
            [field3] => value3
        )
)
```

This is why `count($station)` is 2 -- there are two elements in this associative array. They aren't two rows, they're an element for the model and another element for the related model.

You don't need to use `foreach`, just access the field values in the model.

Comment: OK Barmar. I understood your point. Thanks for clarification.

So how do I count if I want to show the detail records where I expect multiple rows. For example the detail records of the master.